# concate two json object of same key

Tags: arrays, json, object

I have two json object with similar key `question`.

```
var data = {"question":[{
    QuestionID : counter1,
QuestionText: question1, 
    Choices:[{ChoiceID:100,Choice:"Yes",NextQuestionID:counter},
             {ChoiceID:101,Choice:"No",NextQuestionID:counter}],
AnswerType: answer_type
}]};


var data1 = {"question":[{
    QuestionID : counter2,
QuestionText: question2, 
    Choices:[{ChoiceID:103,Choice:"Yes",NextQuestionID:counter},
             {ChoiceID:105,Choice:"No",NextQuestionID:counter}],
AnswerType: answer_type
}]};
```

I want to concate them into one json object with key 'question' and value will be array like below

```
var final = {"question":[
{
    QuestionID : counter1,
QuestionText: question1, 
    Choices:[{ChoiceID:100,Choice:"Yes",NextQuestionID:counter},
             {ChoiceID:101,Choice:"No",NextQuestionID:counter}],
AnswerType: answer_type
},
{
QuestionID : counter2,
QuestionText: question2, 
    Choices:[{ChoiceID:103,Choice:"Yes",NextQuestionID:counter},
             {ChoiceID:105,Choice:"No",NextQuestionID:counter}],
AnswerType: answer_type
}
]};
```

I tried many ways and below way close to my destination but it creats array of data and data1 object

```
var jsons = new Array();
jsons.push(data);
jsons.push(data1);
```

My problem will solve if i can concate `question:Object` and `question:Array[2]` where each index contains object. Final output will be `question:Array[3]`

Any help will be highly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's JavaScript, not JSON. Also, please describe what you've tried and what doesn't work.

Comment: If its just these two, and u need {'question': [q1, q2] } just do a `var myObject = {'question': [data.question, data1.question] };`

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by

```
var index = 0; // number of question
$.each(previousData.question,function(){
           finalArray[index] = previousData.question[index]; //contain array
           index++; //here index is number of question
 });

 finalArray[index] = data.question;
 data = {'question': finalArray }; // convert array to object
```

Answer (score 0):

You can merge through jquery

```
var final = $.merge(data, data1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your code is actually pushing two objects into a list so u get a list of objects. In your case, the first element is data and the second is data1. So you wouldnt actually get the required result.

Since you want an object try this

```
/* assuming data and data1 are created and both have the key question */
var final = {'question': [data.question, data1.question] };

// or using the concat feature
var final = data.question.concat(data1.question);
```

Comment: i am taking 10 questions from user and finally i want like `question:Array[10]` where each array index contain each question. First option works fine till enter two question `question:Array[2]`. But when questions taken more than two it becomes like `question:Array[2]`where Array[0] contain `Array[2]` and Array[1] contain question 3 as object format.